# how to install phonegap for windows8 phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have installed VisualStudio2012 + Windows8 Phone sdk. How can I install PhoneGap for my windows8 apps so that **these apps can be used for android and iPhone too.** I tried it from [PhoneGap Website](http://phonegap.com/) but but it is not going to be installed. I'm making some mistake here.
Visual Studio is projects directory is placed at

> C:\Users\Work-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects

and I installed the NodeJS at

> C:\Program Files

Answer (score 1):

You certainly want to start here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide
Cordova is the new name for PhoneGap open source project.
This guide will get you started with the installation of the Cordova template for Visual Studio and a simple hello world.
If you want to use the Command line tools, you can find instructions here:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface
For CLI use for Windows Phone 8, you only need the WP8 SDK (with VS2012) and node which you seem to have already installed. You will also have to add the path to msbuild.exe to your PATH environment variable.
Good coding!

Comment: If you're going to add plugins also installed git for windows and make sure it's in your path, you'll most likely need that as well! :)

Comment: You may also like to take a look on PhoneGap cloud build to be able to compile iOS version of the app on Windows (https://build.phonegap.com/faq). Android could be compiled right on your local machine along with WP8 app.